# How to load JSON from file into SQL Server 2016?

Tags: json, openrowset, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to move data from JSON format to SQl Server. I' using SQL Server 2016 as this edition supports importing JSON data using OPENROWSET.

I'm using the below to query/import the data but i need some help in parsing the content. Below is my query and the JSON sample file that i'm trying to move to DB.

Query

```
 SELECT value
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\temp\temp.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
```

for the above , im getting results in 2 rows where my first row is some information that i do not need. I would like to know , how would i be able to only select my 2nd row.

Here is the JSON file

```
{
  "meta": {
    "disclaimer": "Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions regarding medical care. While we make every effort to ensure that data is accurate, you should assume all results are unvalidated. We may limit or otherwise restrict your access to the API in line with our Terms of Service.",
    "terms": "https://open.fda.gov/terms/",
    "license": "https://open.fda.gov/license/",
    "last_updated": "2016-05-28",
    "results": {
      "skip": 0,
      "limit": 1,
      "total": 1540390
    }
  },


  "results": [
    {
      "manufacturer_contact_zip_ext": "",
      "manufacturer_g1_address_2": "",
      "event_location": "",
      "report_to_fda": "Y",
      "manufacturer_contact_t_name": "",
      "manufacturer_contact_state": "",
      "manufacturer_link_flag": "Y",
      "manufacturer_g1_city": "ZUG",
      "manufacturer_contact_address_2": "",
      "event_type": "Malfunction",
      "manufacturer_contact_pcity": "",
      "manufacturer_contact_address_1": "GUBELSTRASSE 34",
      "report_number": "3008382007-2012-09245",
      "type_of_report": [
        "Initial submission"
      ],
      "product_problem_flag": "Y",
      "date_received": "20130101",
      "manufacturer_address_2": "",
      "reprocessed_and_reused_flag": "N",
      "manufacturer_address_1": "",
      "manufacturer_contact_zip_code": "6300",
      "manufacturer_contact_plocal": "",
      "reporter_occupation_code": "PATIENT",
      "manufacturer_contact_l_name": "WANDOLSKI",
      "source_type": [
        "Consumer"
      ],
      "distributor_zip_code_ext": "",
      "manufacturer_g1_postal_code": "6300",
      "manufacturer_g1_state": "",
      "date_facility_aware": "20121210",
      "manufacturer_contact_area_code": "",
      "manufacturer_contact_f_name": "YANNICK",
      "previous_use_code": "I",
      "device": [
        {
          "manufacturer_d_address_1": "GUBELSTRASSE 34",
          "manufacturer_d_address_2": "",
          "device_event_key": "",
          "device_sequence_number": " 1.0",
          "manufacturer_d_state": "",
          "manufacturer_d_zip_code": "6300",
          "manufacturer_d_city": "ZUG",
          "lot_number": "3180296",
          "manufacturer_d_postal_code": "6300",
          "manufacturer_d_zip_code_ext": "",
          "model_number": "",
          "date_received": "20130101",
          "device_report_product_code": "NBW",
          "device_operator": "LAY USER/PATIENT",
          "device_availability": "No",
          "other_id_number": "",
          "generic_name": "GLUCOSE MONITORING SYS/KIT",
          "manufacturer_d_name": "LIFESCAN EUROPE, A DIVISION OF CILAG GMBH INTL",
          "manufacturer_d_country": "SZ",
          "brand_name": "OT ULTRALINK METER",
          "openfda": {
            "device_name": "System, Test, Blood Glucose, Over The Counter",
            "medical_specialty_description": "Clinical Chemistry",
            "device_class": "2",
            "regulation_number": "862.1345"
          },
          "device_age_text": "",
          "device_evaluated_by_manufacturer": "R",
          "catalog_number": "",
          "implant_flag": "",
          "date_removed_flag": ""
        }
      ],
      "manufacturer_zip_code": "",
      "manufacturer_contact_country": "SZ",
      "health_professional": "N",
      "manufacturer_g1_zip_code_ext": "",
      "manufacturer_city": "",
      "manufacturer_contact_extension": "",
      "manufacturer_contact_phone_number": "",
      "patient": [
        {
          "sequence_number_treatment": [
            ""
          ],
          "patient_sequence_number": "1",
          "date_received": "20130101",
          "sequence_number_outcome": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      ],
      "distributor_city": "",
      "distributor_state": "",
      "date_report": "20121210",
      "initial_report_to_fda": "Unknown",
      "manufacturer_g1_country": "SZ",
      "event_key": "",
      "manufacturer_contact_city": "ZUG",
      "mdr_report_key": "2891923",
      "removal_correction_number": "",
      "number_devices_in_event": "",
      "date_manufacturer_received": "20121210",
      "manufacturer_name": "",
      "report_source_code": "Manufacturer report",
      "remedial_action": [
        ""
      ],
      "manufacturer_g1_zip_code": "6300",
      "manufacturer_zip_code_ext": "",
      "report_to_manufacturer": "",
      "manufacturer_g1_name": "LIFESCAN EUROPE, A DIVISION OF CILAG GMBH INTL",
      "distributor_address_1": "",
      "adverse_event_flag": "N",
      "manufacturer_state": "",
      "distributor_address_2": "",
      "manufacturer_postal_code": "",
      "manufacturer_country": "",
      "single_use_flag": "N",
      "mdr_text": [
        {
          "mdr_text_key": "16750885",
          "text_type_code": "Description of Event or Problem",
          "patient_sequence_number": "1",
          "text": "ON (B)(6) 2012, THE LAY USER/ PATIENT CONTACTED LIFESCAN (LFS) IN USA ALLEGING AN ER 2 ISSUE. THE PATIENT DID NOT ALLEGE ANY HARM OR INJURY DUE TO THE ALLEGED ISSUE. THE ALLEGED ISSUE WAS NOT RESOLVED WITH TROUBLESHOOTING. BASED ON THE INFORMATION PROVIDED, THERE IS NO INDICATION THAT THE REPORTED ISSUE CAUSED OR CONTRIBUTED TO A SERIOUS INJURY. THE PATIENT DID NOT DEVELOP SYMPTOMS SUGGESTIVE OF SEVERE HYPOGLYCEMIA OR HYPERGLYCEMIA, NOR RECEIVE MEDICAL INTERVENTION FOR EITHER OF THESE CONDITIONS. HOWEVER, THIS COMPLAINT IS BEING REPORTED BECAUSE THE ALLEGED PRODUCT ISSUE REMAINED UNRESOLVED."
        }
      ],
      "number_patients_in_event": "",
      "distributor_name": "",
      "manufacturer_g1_address_1": "GUBELSTRASSE 34",
      "distributor_zip_code": "",
      "manufacturer_contact_exchange": "",
      "manufacturer_contact_postal_code": "6300",
      "manufacturer_contact_pcountry": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "second row", I assume that you want data in "results" object. OPENJSON returns one row per each key:value pair found in the input (only at the first level of input object). In your case you have two objects one under "meta" key, and the other under "results" key.

You can filter second row using [key] column:

```
SELECT value
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\temp\temp.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
WHERE [key] = 'results'
```

Or you can seek into JSON at path $.result and get all nodes within this object:

```
SELECT value
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\temp\temp.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn, '$.results')
```

Maybe you can also take a look at OPENJSON WITH schema that can help you to transform nodes in JSON object as cells, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\temp\temp.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn, '$.results')
WITH (report_number nvarchar(400), date_received nvarchar(400),device nvarchar(max) AS JSON)
```

If you specify NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON as a return type, you can extract JSON fragment (e.g. device array in your example).
If you need some info from the inner array (e.g. device), you can open that JSON array with the second OPENJSON and take info from inner table, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\temp\temp.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn, '$.results')
WITH (report_number nvarchar(400), date_received nvarchar(400),device nvarchar(max) AS JSON)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(device) WITH (lot_number int)
```

Comment: Thanks and this is exactly what i'm looking for ! But how can i request data for nested columns , example : if i only need "lotnumber" from "device" information from the above JSON

Comment: I have updated the answer with new examples. I hope that this is what you need.

Comment: Yup ! Thanks again

Comment: After you reached the deepest level of json, how would you go up the level ?